# Is it possible to constrain a generic parameter type to this?

Tags: c#, generics

**Short version**

How do I force the `BaseClass`'s `TModel` generic parameter to be of the same type as the class that derives from it?

```cs
public class BaseClass<TModel, TValidator> where TValidator : IValidator<TModel> { }

public class Person : BaseClass<Person, PersonValidator> { }
```

In this example, how do I force the `BaseClass`'s `TModel` to be of type `Person` and not something else?

This is invalid syntax, but it's what I'm imagining:

```cs
public class BaseClass<TValidator> where TValidator : IValidator<this> { }

public class Person : BaseClass<PersonValidator> { }
```

Is this somehow possible or should I use a totally different solution to achieve this?

**Long version**

I'm trying to extract some validation logic into a base class, but I don't know how to constraint the generic types so the resulting base class is fully fool-proof.

Here's an example of what all the validation logic looks like without a base class. I'm using FluentValidation to validate the object and I'm exposing that validation result via the `IDataErrorInfo` interface so it can be used by the WPF UI.

**Original solution**

```cs
public class User : IDataErrorInfo 
{
    private readonly IValidator<Person> _validator = new();

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    private string ValidateAndGetErrorForProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        var result = _validator.Validate(this);

        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return result.Errors.FirstOrDefault(a => a.PropertyName == propertyName)?.ErrorMessage ?? string.Empty;
    }

    //IDataErrorInfo implementation
    public string Error => string.Empty;
    public string this[string columnName] => ValidateAndGetErrorForProperty(columnName);
}

public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Username)
            .EmailAddress();

        RuleFor(a => a.Password)
            .MinimumLength(12);
    }
}
```

**Validation implementation separated into a base class**

I'd like to separate the validation logic and `IDataErrorInfo` implementation into a base class so this boilerplate doesn't have to be repeated in every model class. Here's what I have.

```cs
public abstract class ValidationBase<TModel, TValidator> : IDataErrorInfo where TValidator : IValidator<TModel>, new()
{
    private readonly TValidator _validator;

    public ValidationBase()
    {
        _validator = Activator.CreateInstance<TValidator>();
    }

    private string ValidateAndGetErrorForProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        //I have to check if this is of type TModel since the TModel isn't constraint to this
        if (this is not TModel model)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Instance is not of the supported type: {typeof(TModel)}. Type of {GetType()} found instead");
        }

        var result = _validator.Validate(model);

        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return result.Errors.FirstOrDefault(a => a.PropertyName == propertyName)?.ErrorMessage ?? string.Empty;
    }

    //IDataErrorInfo implementation
    public string Error => string.Empty;
    public string this[string columnName] => ValidateAndGetErrorForProperty(columnName);
}
```

And here's how I'm using it:

```cs
public class User : ValidationBase<User, UserValidator>
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**The problem**

The problem I have with this solution is that you can write this invalid code:

```cs
public class InvalidClass : ValidationBase<User, UserValidator>
{
    
}
```

Comment: so.. in short, you dont want none but `User` from implementing `ValidationBase<User, UserValidator>`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Hm, it's your design, but ... is being valid and providing validation-error-information _really_ a concern of the User class itself?

Comment: There appears to be no good reason to have `User` inherit from `ValidationBase` in the first place. Decouple these concerns and the problem disappears. I realize most of the examples in the MSDN have classes implementing `IDataErrorInfo` themselves, but frankly, that's madness -- composition seems much more appropriate than inheritance here. Aside from this, though, how "real" is the problem you're trying to solve, here? Nothing prevents me from writing `class Foo : IEquatable<Bar>` either, and while this makes no sense, it's also very unlikely this mistake will go unnoticed for long.

Comment: ^^ I guess you could even write a Code-Analyzer to check that.

Comment: @Fildor I don't think validation is a concern of the `User` class itself, however, I couldn't get the UI validation to work unless the `User` class itself was implementing the `IDataErrorInfo` interface. My original idea was that the `IDataErrorInfo` would be implemented by a view model that would then hold and validate an instance of `User`, but that didn't work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree, it's not a big deal, but it seemed interesting enough to ask about.

Comment: Off-topic, but use of the `new()` constraint (in this context) is a bad code-smell: parameterless constructors shouldn't exist, imo. If your `TModel` is meant to represent some business/domain object, then presumably it has type invariants and constraints on ctor parameter data that are enforced by the constructor, but requiring or using parameterless constructors means you're creating objects in an indeterminate state, ew.

Comment: "I'd like to separate the validation logic and IDataErrorInfo implementation into a base class" <-- This is an abuse of inheritance. You don't need a supertype for that.

Comment: @Dai I'm only using the `new()` constraint for the `TValidator` type which is an `AbstractValidator<TModel>` (using FluentValidation). All of my validators have parameterless constructors, they're stateless. Is that still a code smell? I thought it was fine.

Comment: @MichalDiviš My apologies, I was speed-reading your code. That said, if your validators are stateless, but still implement interfaces, then why not simplify things greatly by changing `TValidator` from being a generic type-parameter to being a plain ol' `interface` argument passed into the ctor?

Comment: Back on to your original question: you do know that you can do `class BaseClass<TModel,TValidator> where TModel : BaseClass<TModel,TValidator> where TValidator : IValidator<TModel> { }` - right? Does this constrain `TModel` as you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public interface IValidator<TModel>
{
}

public class BaseClass<TModel, TValidator> 
    where TModel : BaseClass<TModel, TValidator> 
    where TValidator 
    : IValidator<TModel> { }

// Only classes derived from BaseClass can be instantiated
public class Person 
    : BaseClass<Person, PersonValidator> { }

public class PersonValidator 
    : IValidator<Person>
{
}
```

This is a classic pattern where a generic parameter is constrained to the derived class.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks to @Dai as well for mentioning this exact solution a little while ago.